# Bootstrap dropdown menu with column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I want to make a vertical dropdown menu that have column just like the one in Microsoft's website without js[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you know the basics of HTML and CSS then you can do it yourself it's easy and fun you know I am providing the link that will help you a lot.
[Creating Hower Able Header DropDowns](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)